# Is it normal to hear soft, high-frequency blips and clicks from an LCD monitor?

Tags: display, lcd

I bought a couple ViewSonic 27" monitors a while back for my dream system, and so far, I've loved them.

Then, all of a sudden, one of them started making strange high-pitched clicking/blinking noises and it got more and more consistent with time. My monitor was still under warranty, so I contacted ViewSonic and shipped it to them yesterday as an RMA (cost a TON of money: note to self, always ship things yourself rather than paying someone else to do it.) Hopefully the refurbished unit I get back will be good quality and will be pretty quiet.

Then, this morning, I realized that the other monitor was doing the same thing, albeit far less often. !$!@%!@!!! Luckily, it has seemed to stop for the time being.

Is this something normal for LCD monitors to do?

Comment: lots of electonics in general can do many of the things you listed, usually it is preventable, by using better method, better parts, overrating the parts, and trying to get people to buy them when they cost 2X after building them that well :-)